# how to make kubernete autoscaler working in ubuntu installation

Tags: kubernetes

I can use auto-scaler in local minikube, but after deploying to ubuntu in aws cloud, I used the same command, the auto-scaler can not reduce the pod automatically.
In local minikube, in order to user auto-scaler, I have to install heapster, may I ask in order to run in cloud ubuntu, what do I need to install so as to make auto-scaler working?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

heapster is now depracted : https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster

To enable auto-scaling on your cluster you can use HPA(horizontal pod auto-scaler) and you can also install metrics server to check all metrics.

Comment: i would suggest offical doc of kubernetes it is best. you cna search for HPA and implementation example everything there.